# Unable to Map JSON object to JqGrid in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

I have a nested JSON object which looks something like this:

[image: JSON Response]

So for my JqGrid looks something like this:

```js
$.post("GetInvoices", {
      v: invoiceno,
      type: invoicetype,
      i: sessioncode
    },
    function(result) {
      $('#list2').jqGrid({
        datastr: result,
        postdata: {
          v: invoiceno,
          type: invoicetype,
          i: sessioncode
        },
        mtype: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['BarCode'],
        colModel: [{
          name: 'BarCode',
          width: 100,
          jsonmap: "DetailProduct.BarCode"
        }],
        loadonce: true

      });
      jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I actually require is to render this JSON object as a grid in my page but it shows undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your datatype to jsonstring

```
    function(result) {
      $('#list2').jqGrid({
        datastr: result,
        mtype: 'POST',
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        colNames: ['BarCode'],
        colModel: [{
          name: 'BarCode',
          width: 100,
          jsonmap: "DetailProduct.BarCode"
        }],
        loadonce: true
      })
...
}
```

since you get already the result data with your post function.